# Cascade.ALL in OneToManyJoin. javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-5.x

I have a detached entity with a One-To-Many join.

```
@Entity
@Table("t1")
class Entity1 implements Serializable {

   ...    

   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="FIELD_1", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "FIELD_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="FIELD_2", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "FIELD_2")
    })  
    public List<Entity2> getListOfEntities() {
        return listOfEntities;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table("t2")
class Entity2 implements Serializable {

   ...

}
```

When I call `entity1Merged = entityManger.merge(entity1)` where entity1 is of class **Entity1**, among other things the `entityManager` falls down to the list of joined entities, loads them from the database, merges them, but apparently the result of the merged **Entity2** objects aren't being assigned to the list **listOfEntities** of the new **entity1Merged**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in version 5.2.12 of hibernate tracked with the issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12054 and resolved from version 5.2.13+.